# Remote Play framework and Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a play framework project which run on remote server.

I'm trying to configure eclipse to work remotely on the project. 
since no build is required my requirements are to be able to edit the project files from eclipse and automatically save on server, auto complete and debug.

I've installed Remote System Explorer on eclipse and setup a remote ftp connection to my server.

The play environment on my server is under
/play-2.0.2/

My project path is
/play-2.0.2/test

In RSE I clicked on /play-2.0.2/test and 'Create Remote Project'

Now in Java perspective I can browse through the project, change files and then automatically save to server.

My problem is auto completion of play framework library doesn't work well since all the reference are to /play-2.0.2/repository/...

any idea how to solve it? I tried to play with the build path but no success

Thanks!

Comment: can't you just use the same paths locally and put the libs there?

Comment: I can try, but the problem is the remote machine is linux so the path is /play-2.0.2/... and the local machine is windows so the path should be c:/play-2.0.2 any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

So, I was looking into achieving the same thing myself.

The problem you are experiencing is due to the fact that the .classpath file has absolute values. While for me, besides the symlink that doesn't work between two different kinds of O.S., I thought on another two solutions:

1. Use sed to rewrite the classpath on the .classpath file after it's generated
2. Use a ["classpathTransformerFactory"](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki/Using-sbteclipse#classpathtransformerfactories) for the sbt eclipse command

I haven't had to deal with it (it's more of want to than whatnot) as soon as I do, I will explore the two options and post details. I just leave the answer here in case someone wants to pick up where you left.

Another thing is:

Seen that `sbt` picks up the libs referenced in `build.sbt`, downloads the jars and puts them in the `~/.ivy2` directory, if you use any of those methods to change the reference from the remote machine to the local one, you would need to make sure that the same libs are on the local ivy cache. So, just as I wrote this, another idea came to mind:

3. `sbt eclipse` or `play eclipse` or `activator eclipse` [it should be the same] on a local environment, and on the remote one, then, transfer the .project and .classpath files from the local to the remote, and see what happens (if it doesn't work, scan them for absolute and incorrect paths that might need to be changed)

Sorry for the unproved answer, still I think it's better than no answer.

Cheers